# Arch Linux performance

Tags: linux, usb, performance, arch-linux

I have Arch Linux installed on a USB 3.0 flash drive - not Live USB, but persistent installation. I have been using this install for a half a year without any issues on an Acer R 15 (i7 CPU, 12 GB RAM) laptop, it runs great. The USB drive is 8GB only, so I have run into disk space shortage and decided to move the install on a freshly bought HP USB 3.1 32GB drive (CrystalDiskMark and hdstat showing 190 MB R / 100 MB W). I have set up partitions and moved the existing system with `rsync -aAXv /* /mnt/new_usb --exclude={/dev/*,/proc/*,/sys/*,/tmp/*,/var/tmp/*,/run/*,/mnt/*,/media/*,/lost+found}`, reinstalled linux init images and grub.

The system boots ok from the new medium, but it is very slow - it used to boot within ~ 15 sec from the old 3.0 USB drive, and now it boots within ~ 2 minutes, with many processes stuck for several seconds at startup (I can see it with systemd while booting). Booted into XFCE, it resembles working at old machines - Chrome startup in 20 - 30 seconds, spontaneous lags while scrolling screens, starting up programs, updating software with pacman, scrolling bash history etc. Hdstat still shows high R/W numbers. I can clearly understand this may go if I installed the system from scratch, but I really need to have it cloned other than reinstalled.

How do I determine what causes this behaviour, and fix it?

Comment: Sequential RW speeds say nothing about the usage pattern of a root file system - most likely your USB stick is just not up to the task - it just isn't goo enough on random reads.

Comment: @EugenRieck, this is very likely, as CrystalDiskMark, as far as I remember, was showing like 0.02 MB RW speed on random 1kb operations but I didn't give it enough attention beforehand. How do I check this more thoroughly, and what is the norm for 3.1 drives? The drive model is HP x5000m 32GB (C+A).

Comment: USB 3.1 is just the interface - and nothing stops you (or HP) from putting a slow flash controller behind a fast interface. To give you an idea: a rotating SATA disk has around 100 IOPS (4K random).